# Proxy a Flask app running on gunicorn to a subpath in nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask app running with gunicorn on `http://127.0.0.1:4000`:

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:4000 webapp:app
```

Now I would like to use nginx as a reverse proxy and forward `http://myserver.com/webapp` to `http://127.0.0.1:4000` in a way that every `http://myserver.com/webapp/subpath` goes to `http://127.0.0.1:4000/subpath`.

The proxy/redirect works nicely when not using a subpath:

```
upstream app {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://app;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;       
    }
}
```

How can I set

```
location /webapp {
    #go to my gunicorn app, translate URLs nicely
}
```

<strike>This tip from the Flask developers didn't work: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/</strike>

SOLVED: The snippet http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/ works! I had a few absolute URLs in my templates (e.g. `/task/delete`) and had to change everything to `url_for()`.

Stupid ... but now it works like expected, I have my app on 'http://myserver.com/subpath'

Comment: Can you just show your controllers in Flask app program?

Comment: So, myserver.com/today is working, but not myserver.com/webapp/today, isn't it?

Comment: @Karthikeyan when I set up the redirect in nginx as described above to location / {}, everything works nicely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved my problem: The snippet http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/ does work, I was so stupid to have absolute URLs in my templates. I changed that to `url_for()` and now it works like charm.

Comment: The URL doesn't seem to work anymore. Could you please provide the solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: FWIW - the content from the original link can be found here (as of today at least): https://web.archive.org/web/20131129080707/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/

Comment: May I ask you how does handle the `next` args in path?